# Incorrect syntax with update and limit

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I created a SQL db file from Superbase, "Dailylog2" I then open the FILE and basically I'm trying to UPDATE a ROW in a Table, dbo.SX_Tom_Table, but Im getting an error.

```
UPDATE [SX_Tom_db].[dbo].[SX_Tom_Table] 
 SET [AI_Field] = Dailylog2.dl_doc_fax 
 FROM Dailylog2 
 WHERE 
   CONVERT(varchar(10), Dailylog2.dl_dos, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(10), 'May/20/2010', 101)   
   AND dl_chart = 912
 LIMIT 1
```

I get the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.

IF I remove the `LIMIT 1` then it works but it updates all the rows. I just want to update the rows selected by the WHERE

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Can you share the error message?  If you run a simple SELECT * with that WHERE clause do you get the specific row you want to update or all the rows?

Comment: select * FROM Dailylog2 
 WHERE 
   CONVERT(varchar(10), Dailylog2.dl_dos, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(10), 'May/20/2010', 101)   
   AND dl_chart = 912
 
Works fine and it finds the 3 records with the WHERE condition

Comment: If I use this code:UPDATE [SX_Tom_db].[dbo].[SX_Tom_Table] 
 SET [AI_Field] = Dailylog2.dl_doc_fax 
 FROM Dailylog2 
 WHERE 
   CONVERT(varchar(10), Dailylog2.dl_dos, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(10), 'May/20/2010', 101)   
   AND dl_chart = 912
 LIMIT 1

Comment: I get the error:Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.

Comment: The one thing I noticed, I'm using SQL2012 Management Studio, the AND is lighter in color as the rest of the statement. AND dl_chart = 912

Comment: If I run the following code it works but it updates all the rows.UPDATE [SX_Tom_db].[dbo].[SX_Tom_Table]
 SET [AL_Field] = Dailylog2.dl_doc_fax 
 FROM Dailylog2
 WHERE  
    (CONVERT(varchar(10), Dailylog2.dl_dos, 101) =  CONVERT(varchar(10), 'May/20/2010', 101) 
 AND Dailylog2.dl_chart = 912)

Comment: (29 row(s) affected)

Comment: To clarify further what I'm trying to accomplish. I have the SX_Tom_Table and there is a column that needs to be UPDATED with what is found on FILE Dailylog2 based on a match for Chart# and Date of Service. The flow should be for every ROW in the SX_Tom_Table update a COLUMN with a match of Date of Service and Chart# found in the FILE Dailylog2

Comment: Your `WHERE` condition looks wrong. `Dailylog2.dl_dos` looks not be a column of the table: `[SX_Tom_db].[dbo].[SX_Tom_Table]`. You should filter by a specific field from that table. I suggest you to do a `SELECT` first an see the returned rows, if it is what you expect than apply it to your `UPDATE`.

Comment: You might be correct. You see Dailylog2 is brought in to the master db via OPEN/FILE in MSQL Studio. I'm able to select all the rows in it, but I guess Dailylog2 is not being treated like a normal TABLE. I'm very new to SQL I apologize. Do you have a solution. Dailylog2.dl_dos shows up as a column when I select * Dailylog2. It is not suppose to be a column in Sx-Tom_Table

Answer (score 0):

For a more accurate answer your should to tell us the columns of each table in the scope of your problem.

**Table: [SX_Tom_db].[dbo].[SX_Tom_Table]**

> Columns: [AI_Field], ?

**Table: [Dailylog2]**

> Columns: dl_dos, dl_chart

The column *X* from the table *[SX_Tom_db].[dbo].[SX_Tom_Table]* must have the same (different...) value from the colum *Y* of the *[Dailylog2]*.

First use the `SELECT` statement to see if your condition returns the expected rows to be changed.

```
SELECT * FROM [SX_Tom_db].[dbo].[SX_Tom_Table] S
-- This inner join you should put the columns that must be equal in both table. 
INNER JOIN 
   [Dailylog2] D ON S.[?] = D.[?]
WHERE  
   CONVERT(varchar(10), D.dl_dos, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(10), 'May/20/2010', 101)   
   AND D.dl_chart = 912
```

If the query above returns the expected rows, than you can apply your `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE 
   S
SET
   [AI_Field] = D.dl_doc_fax
FROM 
   [SX_Tom_db].[dbo].[SX_Tom_Table] S
-- This inner join you should put the columns that must be equal in both table. 
INNER JOIN 
   [Dailylog2] D ON S.[?] = D.[?]
WHERE  
    CONVERT(varchar(10), D.dl_dos, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(10), 'May/20/2010', 101)   
    AND D.dl_chart = 912
```

Comment: Hi Flavio Sorry for not getting back to you sooner. So far I have been able to make some progress. I'm stuck now in comparing 2 date column fields. sx_dos(date,null) with values of 2019-06-15 and Field_Ak(datetime,null) with values of 2011-07-05 00:00:00:000.I have not been able to get a successful compare although the dates appears in both columns on different tables. I have tried using convert and cast with no success. Can you offer any ideas.

Comment: I have use the following code with different data type and with cast and convert.UPDATE [SX_Tom_db].[dbo].[SX_Tom_Table] 
 SET [AI_Field] = Dailylog.sx_fax 
 FROM Dailylog
 WHERE 
   CAST(Dailylog.sx_dos AS VARCHAR(10)) = CAST(AK_Field AS VARCHAR(10))    I have used different data types with no success

Comment: It is hard to help you because we don't know the structure of tables [columns]:  `[SX_Tom_db].[dbo].[SX_Tom_Table]` and `[Dailylog2]`. We don't have a sample of data of both tables and the expected result of what you want. Sorry about this.

Comment: The following is the last code that executes fine but no records are returned. I know for a fact that there are dates with the same values in the SX_Tom_Table and the Dailylog table.SELECT * FROM [SX_Tom_db].[dbo].[SX_Tom_Table] S

 INNER JOIN 
   [Dailylog] D ON S.[AC_Field] = D.[sx_chart]

WHERE  
   CONVERT(varchar(10), D.sx_dos, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(10), S.AK_Field, 101)